# Error with missing package when dockerizing a nuxt app

Tags: javascript, docker, nuxt3

I get this error message when trying run my dockerfile for my nuxt3.5.2 project.

```
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/supports-color/-/supports-5.5.0.tgz: Request failed \"404  
 => => # Not Found\"".
```

Here is my dockerfile

```
FROM node:16-alpine

WORKDIR /app

# Install build dependencies
# RUN apk add --no-cache python3 make g++

# Copy package.json and yarn.lock files
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./

# Install project dependencies
RUN yarn

# Copy the entire project directory
COPY . .

# Build the project
RUN yarn build

# Set environment variables
ENV NODE_ENV=production
ENV NUXT_HOST=0.0.0.0
ENV NUXT_PORT=80

# Expose port 80
EXPOSE 80

# Start the application
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

and here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "web-client",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview",
    "postinstall": "nuxt prepare"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^6.7.0",
    "@tailvue/nuxt": "^1.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^18",
    "@vueuse/core": "^10.1.2",
    "@vueuse/nuxt": "^10.1.2",
    "nuxt": "^3.5.2",
    "nuxt-headlessui": "^1.1.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@pinia/nuxt": "^0.4.11",
    "@vueuse/components": "^10.1.2",
    "pinia": "^2.1.3",
    "vee-validate": "^4.9.5"
  }
}
```

I have tried install adding RUN command to install supports-color@5.5.0 globally but it didnt work at all.

I am really out of options.

Comment: You add this line as a comment it will not execute `# RUN apk add --no-cache python3 make g++`

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the fix.

To fix this, delete the `.lock` file from the project, then re-install the node.js packages.